# How to properly merge multiple collections in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4, foreach, laravel-5

I want to merge multiple collections into one. I do have a solution, which is the following:

```
$allItems = $collection1->merge($collection2)
                        ->merge($collection3)
                        ->merge($collection4)
                        ->merge($collection5);
```

This actually does work, but I run into problems in cases where some or all of the collections contain no objects. I get an error along the lines of `call to merge() on non object`.

I actually tried to create an array of all of the collections, and then iterate through them, while checking their validity, but it didn't work and I feel it wasn't very elegant.

How can I elegantly iterate through this process of merging multiple collections, while taking into account that some or all of the collections might be empty or invalid? Appreciated!

Answer (score 49, accepted):

What I ended up doing was separating each step. It was the merge chaining that was killing it, because some or all of the collections could have been invalid.

```
$allItems = new \Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection; //Create empty collection which we know has the merge() method
$allItems = $allItems->merge($collection1);
$allItems = $allItems->merge($collection2);
$allItems = $allItems->merge($collection3);
$allItems = $allItems->merge($collection4);
```

Comment: It's weird that you can't chain these, but I can confirm that this is correct.

Comment: Just an update for people seeing this you can do `$allItems = collect();` to create a new collection.

Comment: If you merge table collections better to use `->concat($collection1)` instead of `->merge($collection1)` Since two table rows have same id from different tables on will show with **merge**

Comment: Why don't we just make a chain like this `$allItems = $collection1->merge($collection2)->merge($collection3)`?

Answer (score 20):

I had the same question, so I solved it in the following way:

```
$clients = ClientAccount::query()->get();
$admins = AdminAccount::query()->get();

$users = collect($clients)->merge($admins)->merge($anotherCollection)->merge(...);
```

Answer (score 16):

I used `->merge()` but faced a small issue. So I'm adding this in case anyone else face the same issue. `->concat()` is a better solution on database collection merging.

```
$allItems = new \Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection; 
$allItems = $allItems->concat($collection1);
$allItems = $allItems->concat($collection2);
```

The reason for this is when merging they take **ID of the table** as the key. So if two tables have two records with same table id `->merge()` will add only one record to `$allItems`. But `->concat()` will add two records as they should.

Comment: Will merge also work with paginate? For example can we do stuffs like $allItems->paginate(10)

Comment: @SkykidFelix I believe yes. I found this articl https://www.itsolutionstuff.com/post/merge-multiple-collection-paginate-in-laravel-exampleexample.html

Comment: thanks it works. Is there a way to sort the array by 'created_at' => 'DESC'

Comment: Like when you need to fetch the latest post on top?

Comment: @SkykidFelix found this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36169847/laravel-sort-collection-by-date hope this is useful

Answer (score 2):

depend on your data, if collection is actually null or your php support it you can do:

```
    $allItems = $collection1->merge($collection2 ?: collect())
                    ->merge($collection3 ?: collect())
                    ->merge($collection4 ?: collect())
                    ->merge($collection5 ?: collect());
```

or you want to do a reduce:

```
    $allItems = collect([$collection2, $collection3, $collection4])->reduce(function($arr, $item) {
        if (empty($item) || $item->isEmpty())
            return $arr;
        return $arr->merge($item);
    }, $collection1);
```

or plain php reduce without overhead

```
    $allItems = array_reduce([
        $collection2,
        $collection3,
        $collection4
    ], function($arr, $item) {
        if (empty($item) || $item->isEmpty())
            return $arr;
        return $arr->merge($item);
    }, $collection1);
```

Comment: Unfortunately these do not take into account the fact that some or all of the collections could be invalid, incluing $collection1

Answer (score -1):

You could also try:

```
$allItems = collect([
  'collection_1_key' => $collection_1,
  'collection_2_key' => $collection_2,
  'collection_3_key' => $collection_3,
  'collection_4_key' => $collection_4,
]);
```

Comment: This is not a merged collection, it is a collection containing four separate collections.

Answer (score -1):

The easy way to collect different collections in Laravel is using add() function.

For instance; let we have 3 tables namely, directorate, employee, vacancy. Now if we want to retrieve employees to assign them as a jury, they must be under the directorate to which the vacancy job title belongs. But we do not know which employee is under the directorate of the job title, because there may be many vacancies at the same time. To get the directorate of each vacancy, loop through the vacancy within foreach loop. While you are looping select the employee with that directorate for the first item and merge the employee for the rest.

```
 $employees = null;
    if ($vacancies && $vacancies->isNotEmpty()) {
        foreach ($vacancies as $key => $vacancy) {
            if ($employees == null) {
                $employees = Employee::where([
                    'department_id' => $vacancy->directorate_id,
                ])->get();
            } else {
                $employee = Employee::where([
                    'department_id' => $vacancy->directorate_id,
                ])->get();

                if ($employee && $employee->isNotEmpty()) {
                    foreach ($employee as $emp) {
                        $employees->add($emp);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }

    dd($employees);
```

[The output of dump and die](https://i.stack.imgur.com/s7lAV.png)

Comment: The other provided solutions do not involve nested loops and are much simpler.