# Display collection of arrays in blade file Laravel 8

Tags: php, arrays, laravel

I am developing a records where multiple tables record will display in a single view with collection of array. Ref from [merge multiple collection in a single array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32387575/how-to-properly-merge-multiple-collections-in-laravel?answertab=trending#tab-top)

I am seeking help for :

1. How to display collection of array records under **daybookcollection** in a blade file within foreach loop (that stored in a single array.)
2. How to show these records in date wise in ascending order ?

Note : I am not using any relationship method to join these tables because none of these has primary common field.

*There is an another way to solve this issue by create a common transaction table and all tables transaction record master data will save there. From that transaction table display records in a blade file by date wise. But it will create a huge data in that transaction table after certain period of time. And it is not a good process I thought.*

**My Controller**

```
public function daybook_collection()
{
    $vendor_id = Auth::User()->id;
    $data['vendor_profile'] = Vendor_profile::with('vendor_basic')->where('vendor_id', $vendor_id)->first();
    $vendor_sale = Vendorproduct_trn_sale::where('vendor_id', $vendor_id)->get();
    $vendor_salereturn = Vendorproduct_trn_salereturn::where('vendor_id', $vendor_id)->get();
    $vendor_receipt = Vendor_receipt::where('vendor_id', $vendor_id)->get();
    $vendor_payment = Vendor_payment::where('vendor_id', $vendor_id)->get();
    $vendor_purchase = Vendorproduct_trn_purchase::where('vendor_id', $vendor_id)->get();
    $vendor_purchasereturn = Vendorproduct_trn_purchasereturn::where('vendor_id', $vendor_id)->get();
    $vendor_debitnote = Vendor_debitnote::where('vendor_id', $vendor_id)->get();
    $vendor_creditnote = Vendor_creditnote::where('vendor_id', $vendor_id)->get();

    $data['daybookcollection'] = collect($vendor_sale)->merge($vendor_salereturn ?: collect())->merge($vendor_receipt ?: collect())->merge($vendor_payment ?: collect())->merge($vendor_purchase ?: collect())->merge($vendor_purchasereturn ?: collect())->merge($vendor_debitnote ?: collect())->merge($vendor_creditnote ?: collect())->sortBy('transaction_date');

   //dd($data);

  return view('vendor.accountreport.daybook', $data);
}
```

**Array return like this**

[image: collection of arrays]

[image: Expand mode of an array]

**Expected output in blade file**

[image: expected output like this in blade]

Comment: I think its better to compact all these variables to blade and use them in a table?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To do this, while iterating over the `$data['daybookcollection']` Collection, you will need to explain to php how to resolve that specific line through the class of the element we're iterating over. we can use `get_class()` to get that information, in order to tie this all up, add a new array to your controller that maps each possible class with a bill type and id prefix :

```php
public function daybook_collection()
{
//...

 $bill_map = [
   Vendorproduct_trn_sale::class => [
     'type' => 'Sale',
     'prefix' => 'S'
   ],
   Vendor_receipt::class => [
     'type' => 'Receipt',
     'prefix' => 'R'
   ], 
   Vendor_payment::class => => [
     'type' => 'Payment',
     'prefix' => 'Py'
   ] //... Add all the classes you merged
 ];

 return view('vendor.accountreport.daybook', compact('data', 'bill_map'));
}
```

So that inside your blade component, things will look like this :

```php
@foreach($data['daybookcollection'] as $row) 
<tr>
  <td>{{ $row->created_at }}</td> //Date Column
  <td>{{ $bill_map[get_class($row)]['type'] }}</td> //Bill Type Column
  <td>{{ $bill_map[get_class($row)]['prefix'] . $row->id }}</td> //Bill Id Column
  <td> {{ $row->amount }}</td>
</tr>
@endforeach
```

**Warning:** This solution assumes the created_at and amount fields exist in all the models you merged, otherwise for example if some models use an amount field and others use a price field you need to add the column of each class into the bill_map

---

Side-note : Having to resort to collection merges like this is not very clean, i would suggest you create a new abstraction layer, a model named 'Bill' for example, with a polymorphic relationship to all of these types of tables (Vendorproduct_trn_sale, Vendor_receipt..) that gets created and attached everytime an instance of these classes is created, this will make fetching the data for tables like these much easier

Comment: Hello, yes my table has different different name of amount field, like for Vendorproduct_trn_sale = sale_netsale, Vendor_receipt = amount, Vendor_debitnote = debit_amount etc etc.

Comment: In that can do I need to write this way in bill_map ?


$bill_map = [
            Vendorproduct_trn_sale::class => [
              'type' => 'Sale',
              'prefix' => 'S',
              'Transaction_amount' => $vendor_sale->sale_nettotal
            ],

Comment: Well that would be incorrect, to further explain, the $bill_map is more of a helper variable to help the foreach in the blade to resolve to proper values, in your case, the bill_map should look like this :  ```$bill_map = [ Vendorproduct_trn_sale::class => [ 'type' => 'Sale', 'prefix' => 'S', 'Transaction_amount' => 'sale_nettotal' ], ``` while the amount row in the blade section should look like this ```<td> {{ $row->{ $bill_map[get_class($row)['Transaction_amount']] } }</td>```

Comment: I need to precise that in my opinion it's a bad practice to include too much PHP Logic 
 like this within your view logic, views should print variables directly.