# How many model merge in laravel

Tags: laravel

i,m amny crete model
ex: post,story,game,video

Currently, I merge two models and display them in this way:

```
public function show($tags)
    {
        $story = Story::Where('keywords', 'LIKE', "%{$tags}%")->get();
        $post = Post::Where('keywords', 'LIKE', "%{$tags}%")->get();
        $merged = $post->merge($story);
        $results = $merged->paginate(12);
        return view('tags', compact('results'));
    }
```

But now I want to integrate and display the rest of the models
How can I do this?

Thanks

I wrote it like this, but it is not correct:

```
public function show($tags)
    {
        $story = Story::Where('keywords', 'LIKE', "%{$tags}%")->get();
        $post = Post::Where('keywords', 'LIKE', "%{$tags}%")->get();
        $video = Video::Where('keywords', 'LIKE', "%{$tags}%")->get();
        $merged = $post->merge([$story,$video]);
        $results = $merged->paginate(12);
        return view('tags', compact('results'));
    }
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to properly merge multiple collections in Laravel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32387575/how-to-properly-merge-multiple-collections-in-laravel)

Answer (score -1):

You can merge like this

```
$merged = $post->merge($story)->merge($video)->merge($game);
$results = $merged->paginate(12);
return view('tags', compact('results'));
```